# Tellraw or a message in chat at a certain  level in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a world where the sun basically kills you and if you go above sea level during the day you'll die. The problem is that it's really easy to accidentally mine above sea level (whether it be a mountain or a hill, etc) and just die without realizing you went too far up.

I want to display a message a couple of blocks before  63 to the player about to hit the death barrier. I'm on Bedrock.

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you've tried already.  Show us the commands you've tried using, and how they've failed.  It's hard for us to help you when we don't know what it is you're doing wrong.

Comment: I've deleted most of the commands I've used. I'm brand new to using command blocks and I've gotten most of the ones I'm currently using from other threads of people asking similar questions but I haven't been able to find anything online that would help me out, that's why I came here. If it really matters that much I can try and go back to some of the threads I've used but other than that, I don't remember what I've tried. What I do remember though, is that I had literally no success with any of them so I didn't think it would matter which commands I used considering they all failed

Answer (score 3):

You can target players within a volume by using the target selector arguments `x`, `y`, `z`, `dx`, `dy`, and `dz`.

First, to prevent the players from being spammed with tellraw messages, you need to create a scoreboard objective that keeps track of whether the player has been warned or not:

```
/scoreboard objectives add shownWarning dummy
```

Then, put the following command in a repeating, unconditional, needs redstone command block...

```
execute @a[scores={shownWarning=0}] ~ ~ ~ execute @s[x=~,y=63,z=~,dx=0,dy=-<number of blocks>,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @s {"rawtext":{"text":"You are about to hit the death barrier."}}
```

...where `<number of blocks>` is the number of blocks before y=63 where you want to warn the players. This command shows the players who haven't been shown the warning and are in the warning volume the tellraw message.

Put the following in a chain, conditional, always active command block that the first command block is facing. This will set the `shownWarning` objective of the players who have been told the message to 1, which means they have been shown the warning.

```
execute @a[scores={shownWarning=0}] ~ ~ ~ execute @s[x=~,y=63,z=~,dx=0,dy=-<number of blocks>,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @s shownWarning 1
```

Finally, put the following in a repeating, unconditional, needs redstone command block. This will reset the `shownWarning` of the players who are outside of the warning zone.

```
execute @a[scores={shownWarning=1}] ~ ~ ~ execute @s[x=~,y=<62.90 - <number of blocks>>,z=~,dx=0,dy=-<number of blocks>,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @s shownWarning 0
```

For example, if the number of blocks is 5, the `execute @s` part of the command would be:

```
execute @s[x=~,y=57.90,z=~,dx=0,dy=-5,dz=0] ~ ~ ~
```

Link all of the repeating command blocks to a daylight sensor (using redstone) or whatever you are using to detect if it is daytime.

---

## Explanation

Without the scoreboard objective, there would be no way to keep track if a player has already seen the warning. Otherwise, any player within the warning zone would be spammed with messages.

The reason why the commands are split up into `execute @a[scores=... execute @s[x=~...` and not combined like `execute @a[scores=...,x=~...]` is so that the `~` is set to the location of the player, not the command block.

### First command

- `execute @a[scores={shownWarning=0}] ~ ~ ~` Execute as all the players who have not been shown the warning (shownWarning=0).
- `execute @s[x=~,y=63,z=~,dx=0,dy=-<number of blocks>,dz=0] ~ ~ ~` Execute if the player is also within the volume between y=63 and y=63 - <number of blocks>. As `x`, `z`, `dx`, and `dz` are also required when using `y` and `dy`, they are set to test if the player is in the x and z coordinates of the player (which will always be the case).
- `tellraw @s {"rawtext":{"text":"You are about to hit the death barrier."}}` The tellraw message.

### Second command

- `execute @a[scores={shownWarning=0}] ~ ~ ~` Same as the first command.
- `execute @s[x=~,y=63,z=~,dx=0,dy=-<number of blocks>,dz=0] ~ ~ ~` Same as first command.
- `scoreboard players set @s shownWarning 1` Sets the players who have not been shown the warning and are in the warning zone's `shownWarning` to 1. This is so they don't get spammed with messages. This command occurs after the first command (because it's a chain command block).

### Third command

- `execute @a[scores={shownWarning=1}] ~ ~ ~` Execute as all the players who have been shown the warning (shownWarning=1).
- `execute @s[x=~,y=<62.99 - <number of blocks>>,z=~,dx=0,dy=-<number of blocks>,dz=0] ~ ~ ~` This is similar to the other commands except for the volume that it's testing. Instead of testing if the player is in the warning zone, it is testing if it is below it. The reason why `y` is 62.99 - <number of blocks> is because it is 0.01 blocks below the start of the warning zone.
- `scoreboard players set @s shownWarning 0` Sets the players who are outside of the warning zone's `shownWarning` to 0, which allows them to see the warning again if they enter get close to the death barrier.

---

Because you mentioned that you're brand new to using command blocks, here are some pages on the Minecraft wiki that you can read for more information:

- [Scoreboard](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard)
- [`execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#Bedrock_Edition)
- [`tellraw`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tellraw) ([Raw JSON text in BE](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_raw_JSON_text_format))

Comment: That's one hell of a response, lol. Extremely helpful though. I'll try it when I get home and I'll get back to you

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I've been really busy and haven't had a good chance to try this out until now. I haven't gotten it to work despite following your exact instructions. Do you have an Xbox gamertag? Lol, I feel like I'm not cut out for this

Comment: Either that or I could tell you what the command blocks are saying is the issue. I've messed around with fixing their "issues" and inserting things I've seen from other commands but no dice.

Comment: @Hydrality What do the command blocks say then?

Comment: Command #1 says "Duplicate y selector arguments"  Command #2 says "Unexpected "{" at "Execute @s>>{<<x=~,y=63,z" But I changed to to a bracket and the message hasn't changed so I think I may have fixed it. Lastly, Command #3 says "Unexpected "-" at "~,y=62.90 >>-<< 5>,z=~,dx"

Comment: @Hydrality Sorry about that, I updated my answer. The first command was a typo and I wasn't clear on the syntax of the 3rd command: see my updated answer.

Comment: So I've entered everything correctly I think, but it hasn't worked. The command blocks aren't giving me an error or anything. I'm not sure what I've done wrong, should I always enter the <block amount> as 57.90? As of now I have it set to -5

Comment: @Hydrality If you want to warn players within 5 blocks, the third command would be `execute @a[scores={shownWarning=1}] ~ ~ ~ execute @s[x=~,y=57.90,z=~,dx=0,dy=-<number of blocks>,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @s shownWarning 0` as 62.90 - 5 = 57.90.

Comment: That's what I have it set as currently.

Comment: Would I also set the dy to -5??

Comment: @Hydrality Yes, the `dy` would also be -5.

Comment: That's what I have it set to. I'm confused